# Is there any jquery to detect if the html tag was not closed? or page has not completely loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, onload

I'm experiencing an issue (which I still need to fix) where my entire page does not load. It gets cut off in the middle of an element.

Is there a way using jquery or javscript to do something like:

if (some element has not loaded yet) {refresh the page}

I was thinking of just putting `<div id="end_of_page"></div>` at the bottom of the page, and checking if that was rendered, if not, i'll know something went wrong and can reload to try again.

thanks!!

Comment: That cut-off sounds to be a server issue, and should be detected there.

Comment: Are you sure it's a HTML problem? Could there be some incorrect javascript? Use the browser's developer tools to check the DOM tree for any inconsistencies or errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way using jquery or javscript to do something like:
>
> if (some element has not loaded yet) {refresh the page}

You **can** do that, yes. Put this in the head after including jQuery:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    if (!$("#end_of_page")[0]) {
        // Something went wrong, load again
        location.reload();
    }
});
</script>
```

You'll enter the body of the loop (and so, force a reload) if the `end_of_page` element doesn't exist as of when the jQuery `ready` event fires (which is meant to be when the page is done loading).

**But:** Better *by far* to figure out why your page is getting cut off half-way through and solve that. This sort of workaround is not a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! Yes, believe me, I'm not happy I have to do this either!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // code here
});
```

that code will only run when the page has loaded. A convenient shorthand is:

```
$(function(){
   // code here
});
```

assuming your jQuery object is `$`. To finish your requirement, you can have a variable that is set within the load function, then use a timer set at the start of the page to check for it. If it's not there, reload.

Personally, I think you should invest some time into figuring out *why* your pages only half-way (Firebug or the Chrome Inspector may help you do this, it might be a resource in your page that is causing it to hang, and since most HTTP requests are only made 2 at a time per hostname, it might be waiting for that to return before fetching the rest).

Answer (score 1):

Might be a server-side issue **OR** some script or library is stealing your **fish** `$` (AKA: 'Dollar').

I'll rather suggest you to debug your code instead of refreshing the page trying to fix issues.

Make sure your scripts are in the `head` of your document,
 and **jQuery** + your **jQ functions** right before the closing `</body>` tag wrapped in:

```
(function($){ /*your functions*/ })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Adding to your answer: in the past i've dealt with a few megabytes pages, in an effort to improve loading times I decided to compress the html - remove spaces, \t and \n\r - to my astonishment it reduced the page sizes in 30% average and improved loading times a lot (it was PHP with lots and lots of useless junk).